# How to calculate mean difference for effect size calculation?

Tags: t-test, effect-size, paired-data, cohens-d, differences

For a two-sample effect size calculation on paired data (or a one-sample test on differences), does it make sense for an effect size to be negative for a hypothetical % increase of a mean? I’m doing a one-sided test. I have seen 2 versions of the mean difference and I’m not sure if it changes depending on an increase/decrease or if it’s always the same equation.

Is it $(m_1 - m_0)/sd$ or $(m_0 - m_1)/sd$, where $m_1$ is the mean at a second time point (the alternative) and $m_0$ is the starting mean (the null)? I know order doesn’t matter for a two-sided test, but for a one-sided test I think it’s the former equation.

Comment: The effect size is what it is, regardless of the direction of the test.  The order of subtraction doesn't matter, but you do have to interpret it correctly and make that interpretation consistent with your alternative hypothesis.  For instance, when you have 2 apples and your neighbor has 5, you can express the difference either as "my neighbor has 5-2 more apples than me" or "I have 2-5 apples more than he."  (The latter is usually rendered in English as "I have 5-2 apples less than he does.")  All those statements mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cohen's $d$ can be positive or negative, so only the magnitude of the difference is important and the interpretation of *which* mean is larger than the other. This is because the formula for $d$ could be:

$$
d = \frac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2}{\text{pooled SD}}
$$

Or very easily just:

$$
d = \frac{\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1}{\text{pooled SD}}
$$

Where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of a given group and the pooled SD is the combined standard deviation of both groups. Thus here only the reference group matters, or which group we are comparing the other group to. So long as you know the absolute magnitude of the effect and whether the means increase/decrease over time, then there is no real importance to placement of the mean terms.

Comment: I see, so the equation should include the absolute value sign up top then, no? Not trying to be annoying! Haha, I've just seen many versions of this equation.

Comment: I wouldn't say the absolute sign is necessary because the sign can still tell you which direction the effect is going (in terms of which mean is bigger/smaller). But if you just want to think of it in terms of "how big the effect is" then that isn't an entirely wrong way of thinking about it.